# How to generate an argument list in a shell command from ansible based on a host_vars list

Tags: bash, ansible

in an ansible script I want to specify the generation of letsencrypt certificates via certbot. Via the domain option I want to the cert to embrace as many domains as I wish to register. Everything works as expected when hardcoded like this:

```
  command: |
    certbot certonly \
    --standalone \
    --non-interactive \
    --agree-tos \
    --email me@you.com \
    -d domain1.com \
    -d domain2.com \
    -d domain3.com
```

Since the script shall be more host specific / generic I was wondering: Is it somehow possible to generate the upper list of '-d domainx.com's from an ansible item list residing in my `host_vars/<specific_host>.yml`? I don't know if that would be more of a bash or an ansible related type of question, that's why I tagged it with both :D

Best and thanks!
Andi

Comment: Unless you've done work to change this, the shell running your ansible commands is `sh`, not `bash` (if it were the latter, arrays would be available so I would have given a different answer).

Comment: An aside -- don't use all those backslash line ending escapes. Use `>` instead of `|` and it will stack it all on one line anyway. You can even still use Charles' solution if you delimit commands with `;`.

Answer (score 1):

@CharlesDuffy: Unfortunately your solution didn't work for us. Nevertheless, the `join()` function was a valuable hint. Using `join()` we simply created a second variable in our host file processing the list of domains like so

```
 certbot_certificate_domains:
    - domain1.com
    - domain2.com
    - domain3.com

 certbot_domain_list: "-d {{ certbot_certificate_domains | join(' -d ') }}"
```

In our command we then referenced the value of the variable:

```
 name: run initial letsencrypt
   command: 
     certbot certonly --standalone --non-interactive --agree-tos --rsa-key-size 4096 --email me@you.com {{ certbot_domain_list }}
```